# WARNING, No "Setup" File Exists, Running "buildconfig/config.py" how to fix that?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I break the problem to you all real quick. Basicly I can't install many thing from python pip to install a library. Also if I run as an example an image detector using python, the windows will close after several milliseconds. Here is the libary problem.

C:\Users\culde\source\repos>pip install pygame ("--pre" also tried that)
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting pygame
Using cached pygame-2.4.0.tar.gz (13.2 MB)
Installing build dependencies ... done
Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [92 lines of output]

```
  WARNING, No "Setup" File Exists, Running "buildconfig/config.py"
  Using WINDOWS configuration...

  Making dir :prebuilt_downloads:
  Downloading... https://www.libsdl.org/release/SDL2-devel-2.26.4-VC.zip 0dea77fd5ead8c1a2134af3fc256578327e25879
  Unzipping :prebuilt_downloads\SDL2-devel-2.26.4-VC.zip:
  Downloading... https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_image/release/SDL2_image-devel-2.0.5-VC.zip 137f86474691f4e12e76e07d58d5920c8d844d5b
  Unzipping :prebuilt_downloads\SDL2_image-devel-2.0.5-VC.zip:
  Downloading... https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL_ttf/releases/download/release-2.20.1/SDL2_ttf-devel-2.20.1-VC.zip 371606aceba450384428fd2852f73d2f6290b136
  Unzipping :prebuilt_downloads\SDL2_ttf-devel-2.20.1-VC.zip:
  Downloading... https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL_mixer/releases/download/release-2.6.2/SDL2_mixer-devel-2.6.2-VC.zip 000e3ea8a50261d46dbd200fb450b93c59ed4482
  Unzipping :prebuilt_downloads\SDL2_mixer-devel-2.6.2-VC.zip:
  Downloading... https://github.com/pygame/pygame/releases/download/2.1.3.dev4/prebuilt-x64-pygame-2.1.4-20220319.zip 16b46596744ce9ef80e7e40fa72ddbafef1cf586
  Unzipping :prebuilt_downloads\prebuilt-x64-pygame-2.1.4-20220319.zip:
  copying into .\prebuilt-x64
  Path for SDL: prebuilt-x64\SDL2-2.26.4
  ...Library directory for SDL: prebuilt-x64/SDL2-2.26.4/lib/x64
  ...Include directory for SDL: prebuilt-x64/SDL2-2.26.4/include
  Path for FONT: prebuilt-x64\SDL2_ttf-2.20.1
  ...Library directory for FONT: prebuilt-x64/SDL2_ttf-2.20.1/lib/x64
  ...Include directory for FONT: prebuilt-x64/SDL2_ttf-2.20.1/include
  Path for IMAGE: prebuilt-x64\SDL2_image-2.0.5
  ...Library directory for IMAGE: prebuilt-x64/SDL2_image-2.0.5/lib/x64
  ...Include directory for IMAGE: prebuilt-x64/SDL2_image-2.0.5/include
  Path for MIXER: prebuilt-x64\SDL2_mixer-2.6.2
  ...Library directory for MIXER: prebuilt-x64/SDL2_mixer-2.6.2/lib/x64
  ...Include directory for MIXER: prebuilt-x64/SDL2_mixer-2.6.2/include
  Path for PORTMIDI: prebuilt-x64
  ...Library directory for PORTMIDI: prebuilt-x64/lib
  ...Include directory for PORTMIDI: prebuilt-x64/include
  DLL for SDL2: prebuilt-x64/SDL2-2.26.4/lib/x64/SDL2.dll
  DLL for SDL2_ttf: prebuilt-x64/SDL2_ttf-2.20.1/lib/x64/SDL2_ttf.dll
  DLL for SDL2_image: prebuilt-x64/SDL2_image-2.0.5/lib/x64/SDL2_image.dll
  DLL for SDL2_mixer: prebuilt-x64/SDL2_mixer-2.6.2/lib/x64/SDL2_mixer.dll
  DLL for portmidi: prebuilt-x64/lib/portmidi.dll
  Path for FREETYPE: prebuilt-x64
  ...Library directory for FREETYPE: prebuilt-x64/lib
  ...Include directory for FREETYPE: prebuilt-x64/include
  Path for PNG not found.
  ...Found include dir but no library dir in prebuilt-x64.
  Path for JPEG not found.
  ...Found include dir but no library dir in prebuilt-x64.
  DLL for freetype: prebuilt-x64/lib/freetype.dll
  DLL for png: prebuilt-x64/SDL2_image-2.0.5/lib/x64/libpng16-16.dll

  ---
  For help with compilation see:
      https://www.pygame.org/wiki/CompileWindows
  To contribute to pygame development see:
      https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
  ---

  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
      main()
    File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 335, in main
      json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 118, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
      return hook(config_settings)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    File "C:\Users\culde\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-qe35phqc\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 341, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
      return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=['wheel'])
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    File "C:\Users\culde\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-qe35phqc\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 323, in _get_build_requires
      self.run_setup()
    File "C:\Users\culde\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-qe35phqc\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 488, in run_setup
      self).run_setup(setup_script=setup_script)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    File "C:\Users\culde\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-qe35phqc\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 338, in run_setup
      exec(code, locals())
    File "<string>", line 400, in <module>
    File "C:\Users\culde\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-nvkmvj_4\pygame_9bb7191a4f004cf989da93ad39f0ef15\buildconfig\config.py", line 231, in main
      deps = CFG.main(**kwds, auto_config=auto)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    File "C:\Users\culde\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-nvkmvj_4\pygame_9bb7191a4f004cf989da93ad39f0ef15\buildconfig\config_win.py", line 493, in main
      return setup_prebuilt_sdl2(prebuilt_dir)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    File "C:\Users\culde\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-nvkmvj_4\pygame_9bb7191a4f004cf989da93ad39f0ef15\buildconfig\config_win.py", line 453, in setup_prebuilt_sdl2
      DEPS.configure()
    File "C:\Users\culde\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-nvkmvj_4\pygame_9bb7191a4f004cf989da93ad39f0ef15\buildconfig\config_win.py", line 336, in configure
      from . import vstools
    File "C:\Users\culde\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-nvkmvj_4\pygame_9bb7191a4f004cf989da93ad39f0ef15\buildconfig\vstools.py", line 8, in <module>
      compiler.initialize()
    File "C:\Users\culde\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-qe35phqc\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\msvc9compiler.py", line 403, in initialize
      vc_env = query_vcvarsall(VERSION, plat_spec)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    File "C:\Users\culde\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-qe35phqc\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\msvc9compiler.py", line 281, in query_vcvarsall
      raise DistutilsPlatformError("Unable to find vcvarsall.bat")
  distutils.errors.DistutilsPlatformError: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat
  [end of output]
```

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.

I have tried to figure out the problem but no logs can be recorded with any method. I all ready tried using the commandline "input()" too for my problem. Thanks for helping me in advance.